# Change Xaxis values to time using canvas js?

Tags: javascript, canvas

The problem I am encountering is that I want to change the X values from just incrementing to current time with (hour:minute:second)? I have been working on this for more than 2-3 hours, and I know there is a way to solve this problem..

If I have for instance 3 different samples:

1. Data - 14.33.45
2. Data - 14.33.46
3. Data - 14.33.47

[Click here to view the diagram and edite too](http://canvasjs.com/editor/?id=http://canvasjs.com/example/gallery/dynamic/realtime_line/)

Kind regards
Dler H.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean but if you want to show the time in the x axis you should replace `x: xVal,` to `x: new Date(),`.

If you are looking to change the speed of when the chart is updated you will need to change `var updateInterval = 20;` to `var updateInterval = 1000;`. This will mean the chart will update every 1000 millisecond's (1 second).

Comment: I have tried this "x: new Date()", but then it will show "Tue Apr 28 2015 21:43:49 GMT+0200" and I want it to be instance 14.33.56.

Comment: Add `toLocaleTimeString()` to the end of date. When I changed the code on the link it worked for me with just new date but that may be due to the date settings for my region.

Comment: Could you specify what you changed? Like this new Date().toLocaleTimeString()?

Comment: `for (var j = 0; j < count; j++) { 
    yVal = yVal +  Math.round(5 + Math.random() *(-5-5));
    dps.push({
     x: new Date(),
     y: yVal
    });
    xVal++;
   };`

Comment: I have tried it, and it looks weird.. Because it does not move with the x-axis? If you try setting x: new Date(), you can clearly see what I am talking about.

Comment: That's due to the array being populated at runtime. It starts at 0 and goes up to dataLength which in this case is set to 500. When the array reaches 500 it removes the first record and adds a new record. If you prepopulate the array with 500 blank results then the time will show immediately.

Comment: Thank you, but this does not work. The values that I receive is from an sensor. I want the data to have time. I will work on this an give you an answer when I have the solution, thank you for your help and time.